# How to remove GRUB Rescue prompt after deleting Ubuntu partition?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I had a Windows 7 pc dual booting with Windows XP and then i got hold of Ubuntu 12.10 and I installed  it alongside Windows 7 and after installing on boot i got GNU GRUB interfering in my bootloader and after some days I by mistake formatted the parttion now my pc does not boot and shows grub rescue

Comment: Please re-phrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

if you again install ubuntu (or any distro) alongside your windows then you can get both OSes again.Or if you dont want to use dual boot then install your windows again.You should format drive c while installing new windows in it.Your problem will be solved.